# Trailing slash .htaccess rules causing full internal location to be used

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess

This is a fairly simple problem that's been addressed all over the web, but I can't find the solution to my problem.

I'm trying to force a trailing slash on URLs on my website with this .htaccess file:

```
# Don't allow directory indexing
Options -Indexes -Multiviews

# Turn on the URL rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

    # Add trailing slashes  
    RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME}      -d
    RewriteRule    ^(.+[^/])$       $1/     [R]

    # send the request to [first pseudo-directory].php?p=[all the rest]

    # not a known file or directory
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d

    #exclude URIs with a dot in them
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}      !\..+$

    RewriteRule     ^(.*?)/(.*)$        $1.php?p=$2 [L,NS]

# Handle other errors
ErrorDocument 404 /errors.php?code=404
ErrorDocument 500 /errors.php?code=500
```

However, when someone visits `http://domain.tld/mobile/hours` (no trailing slash), it gets redirected to `http://domain.tld/var/www/html/mobile/hours/` which has the trailing slash, but inexplicably also has the full internal path, which results in a 404 error, for obvious reasons.

Of course, the correct result I am looking for is `http://domain.tld/mobile/hours/`

Any hints?

Comment: What's the `<VirtualHost>` configuration look like?  Any maybe see what you get from a `RewriteLog` with `RewriteLogLevel` turned up to 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity:

Modifying the `.htaccess` file below the `RewriteEngine On` line to look like this:

```
RewriteBase /

        # Add trailing slashes
        RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME}              !-f
        RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_URI}                   !(.*)/$
        RewriteRule    ^(.*)$                           http://sub.tld.com/$1/         [L,R=301]
```

...apparently fixed the issue.  Not sure what I did differently this time, as I've made all these changes before, but it's working now.  I think it might be related to the explicit URL and the `RewriteBase /` rules.

For a little more info, see [this short tutorial](http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/trailing-slash/).

Thanks for everyone's help, I'm not 100% sure what fixed this, but hopefully these lines can help someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this Rule:

```
RewriteRule    ^(.+[^/])$       $1/     [R]
```

To include a slash before your backreference:

```
RewriteRule    ^(.+[^/])$       /$1/     [R]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this resulted in no change whatsoever.

Comment: I wonder if this is conflicting with [mod_dir's DirectorySlash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) (which is usually turned on by default). Maybe turning `DirectorySlash off` might help?

Comment: I added `DirectorySlash off` to the top of the .htaccess file, and it didn't change the behavior at all.  On another note, I've created [this question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513414/forced-trailing-slash-redirect-rule-causing-strange-results) because I think the issue might be related to jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `L` flag as strongly recommended by the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) like

```
RewriteRule    ^(.+[^/])$       /$1/     [R,L]
```

It will make the evaluation of the rules stop at this point and emit the redirect with the then-current rewritten URL.

If you omit the `L` following rules will still be execute and further rewrites will occur with the final rewrite being from the URL to the filesystem path. Only then, the actual redirect would occur with the then final path that you can observe in your current response.

Comment: This didn't change the result.